# Website Contact Page redirects to home page when typing in field

Tags: wordpress

If I go to my client's contact page here: http://renosculptureservices.com/contact/ and click in any of the textboxes I automatically get sent to the home page. I have tried this in Chrome and in Firefox and it happens in both. I am not sure what is causing it. Any help would be appreciated. The website is built with Wordpress and is using Contact Form 7.

Comment: It's look like you have a non-close <a> before the cf7 shortcode, but i'm with my phone, I can't verify...

Comment: That was it! Somehow the shortcode got linked. Thanks!